# Retrieving textResponse property from a ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var getTemplateCall = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data
});
console.log(getTemplateCall);
```

This code will show me a break down of the ajax response in the console including 'responseText' property and its contents.

I want to access just the response text as a variable so I have tried

```
console.log(getTemplateCall.responseText);
console.log(getTemplateCall['responseText']);
```

These both returned 'undefined' when what I actually want to see is the contents of the responseText property. I think this is a syntax problem.

What is the correct way to access the responseText?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTemplateCall` does not contain the *result* of your async query. It contains *your async query*. Use `getTemplateCall.done(...)`

From the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

```
var getTemplateCall = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data
});

getTemplateCall.done( data => { // This is the callback of your asynchronous call
     console.log(data);
})
```

or just :

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data
    }).done( data => {
         console.log(data);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

do not write it together,execute:

```
var getTemplateCall = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data
});
```

after one second,execute:

```
console.log(getTemplateCall.responseText);
```

if you write it together,you will get undefined because the browser is sending the ajax-request.So,you have to wait for a second.
actually the native code is like this:

```
var xhr=new new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(url, 'get');
xhr.onreadystatechange=function () {
    // the readystate is changing,when the readystate===4
    // the request is done,then ,we can get the data
    //do something
};
xhr.send();
```